# Child components not updating global state

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, use-effect

I am developing a form with controlled components, Material-UI and, react hooks. All of the form data is saved in a global state via a useState setter function.
Additionally, some fields need to be toggled on and off depending on the user's response which implies that its local and global state has to be reset when toggled off.

That said when two or more components are toggled off at the same time one of them fails to update the global form state.

Here is my code:

App.js

```
imports...

function App () {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    fullName: '',
    email: '',
    ageLevel: '',
    numTitle: '',
    titleTypes: '',
    materialType: '',
    subjInterest: ''
  })

  const handleTxtFldChange = (e, name) => {
    setFormState({ ...formState, [name]: e.target.value })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='App'>
        <form noValidate autoComplete='off'>
          <TextField
            required
            value={formState.fullName}
            onChange={e => handleTxtFldChange(e, 'fullName')}
            label='fullName:'
          />
          <AgeLevelSelect
            formState={formState}
            setFormState={setFormState}
          />
          <NumOfTitles
            formState={formState}
            setFormState={setFormState}
            ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
          />
          <MaterialType
            formState={formState}
            setFormState={setFormState}
            ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
          />
          <SubjOfInterest
            formState={formState}
            setFormState={setFormState}
            ageLevel={formState.ageLevel}
            materialType={formState.materialType}
          />
          <Button
            onClick={() => { submitForm() }}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

When **Adult is selected from AgeLevelSelect**, numTitle and materialType will be toggled on.
The data is saved in its local and global sate.
Component: AgeLevelSelect.js

```
imports...

const AgeLevelSelect = ({ formState, setFormState }) => {
  const [age, setAge] = useState('')

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value)
    setFormState({ ...formState, ageLevel: event.target.value })
  }
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <InputLabel>Age level?</InputLabel>
      <Select
        value={age}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <MenuItem value='School-Age'>School-Age</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value='Teens'>Teens</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value='Adults'>Adults</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  )
}

export default AgeLevelSelect
```

Here we **select two from the select options**. The data is saved in its local and global sate.
Component: NumOfTitles.js

```
imports...

const NumTitles = ({ formState, setFormState, ageLevel }) => {
  const [titles, setTitles] = useState('')
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState('')

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setTitles(event.target.value)
    setFormState({ ...formState, numTitle: event.target.value })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ageLevel === 'Adults') {
      setIsVisible(true)
    } else {
      setValue('')
      setIsVisible(false)
      setFormState(prevState => {
        return { ...formState, materialType: '' }
      })
    }
  }, [ageLevel])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ageLevel !== 'Adults') {
      setFormState(prevState => {
        return { ...formState, materialType: '' }
      })
      setValue('')
      setIsVisible(false)
    }
  }, [value])

  return (
    isVisible &&
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel id='demo-simple-select-label'>Number of titles:</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={titles}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value='One'>One</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value='Two'>Two</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
  )
}

export default NumTitles
```

If you made it this far **THANK YOU**. We are almost done.
Here we **select Non-fiction**. Data gets save in local and global state.
Additionally, the subject of interest question is toggled on.
Component: MaterialType.js

```
imports...

const TypeOfMaterial = ({ formState, setFormState, ageLevel }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState('')

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
    setFormState({ ...formState, materialType: event.target.value })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ageLevel === 'Adults') {
      setIsVisible(true)
    } else {
      setValue('')
      setIsVisible(false)
      setFormState(prevState => {
        return { ...formState, materialType: '' }
      })
    }
  }, [ageLevel])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isVisible) {
      setFormState(prevState => {
        return { ...formState, materialType: '' }
      })
      setValue('')
      setIsVisible(false)
    }
  }, [isVisible])

  return (
    isVisible &&
      <FormControl component='fieldset'>
        <FormLabel component='legend'>Select type of material:</FormLabel>
        <RadioGroup name='MaterialTypes' value={value} onChange={handleChange}>

          <FormControlLabel
            value='Mystery'
            control={<Radio />}
            label='Mystery'
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            value='NonFiction'
            control={<Radio />}
            label='Non-fiction'
          />
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
  )
}

export default TypeOfMaterial
```

Finally, we **write World War II, in the text field**. The data is saved in its local and global sate.
Component: SubjOfInterest.js

```
imports...

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

const SubjOfInterest = ({ formState, setFormState, ageLevel, materialType }) => {
  const [textField, setTextField] = useState('')
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState('')

  const handleTxtFldChange = (e) => {
    setTextField(e.target.value)
    setFormState({ ...formState, subjInterest: e.target.value })
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (formState.materialType === 'NonFiction') {
      setIsVisible(true)
    } else {
      setIsVisible(false)
    }
  }, [materialType])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formState.materialType !== 'NonFiction') {
      setTextField('')
    }
  }, [ageLevel])
  return (
    isVisible &&
      <TextField
        value={textField}
        onChange={e => handleTxtFldChange(e)}
        label='Indicate subjects of interest:'
      />
  )
}

export default SubjOfInterest
```

At this point the global state looks as follow:

```
{  
  fullName:"Jhon Doe", 
  ageLevel:"Adults", 
  numTitle:"Two",  
  materialType:"NonFiction",  
  subjInterest:"World War"  
}
```

Then if a user changes the selected option (Adults) from the AgeLeveleSelect to a different option (teens for example) the a part of global state (numTitle, materialType, subjInterest) is expected to be cleared, instead I get this:

```
{  
  fullName:"Jhon Doe", 
  ageLevel:"Teens", 
  numTitle:"Two",  
  materialType:"",  
  subjInterest:"World War"  
}
```

Any ideas?
I have tried many things without results.
If anyone can help will be **greatly appreciated!!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only clearing the materialType field:

- On the NumOfTitles.js file you are setting the field "materialType" instead of the "numOfTitles" field.
- On the SubjOfInterest.js you are not clearing any fields.

My suggestion is that you check the "Adults" condition on the parent component. This way you will not update the same state three times (if this occurs at the same time, this can cause some problems).

You can try doing this way:
App.js

```
function App () {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    fullName: '',
    email: '',
    ageLevel: '',
    numTitle: '',
    titleTypes: '',
    materialType: '',
    subjInterest: ''
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if(formState.ageLevel !== 'Adults') {
      setFormState({
        ...formState,
        numTitle: '',
        materialType: '',
        subjInterest: '',
      })
    }
  }, [formState.ageLevel]);
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you! moving the useEffect method to the parent component  fixed the problem.